# Creating a Simple Recommendation System in Python

Tags: python, graph

I am trying to create a simple recommendation system that recommends users the books that their friends are reading. I have created a class called 'recommendation' that captures users details like name, user's friends, user's books and recommended books (friend's books). Now the issue is when the instance of user 'A' gets created, 'A's recommended books list is empty as its friend 'B' has not been instantiated as yet. When 'B' does get instantiated, 'A' still has no clue about B's books as 'A' has been instantiated before 'B'. Is there a way to fix this?

```
from collections import defaultdict


class recommendation: 
    friendsgraph =  defaultdict(set)  # key: user, value: friends of users
    booksgraph =  defaultdict(set)    # key: user, value: books of user       

    def __init__(self, user, books, friends):
        self.name = user
        self.books  = books
        self.friends = friends
        self.recommended_books = friendsbooks(friends)

        recommendation.friendsgraph[user] = friends
        recommendation.friendsgraph[user] = books

    def friendsbooks(friends):
        recommendation_list = set()
        for friend in friends:
            rec_books = recommendation.booksgraph[friend]
            if rec_books:
                recommendation_list.add(rec_books)
            else:
                recommendation_list = ()
        return recommendation_list


A = recommendation('A',('Harry Potter'),('B'))
B = recommendation('B',('Harry Potter', 'Master Algo'),('A','C'))
```

One way to work around this is to pass dictionaries of friends and books as attributes, and write a separate method that would recommend books. This way each user will be aware of its friends and their books at the time of instantiation. This strategy, however, takes away the ability to associate attributes to individual users (such as A.recommended_books).

```
class recommendation:            

    def __init__(self):
        self.friendsgraph = defaultdict(set)
        self.booksgraph  = defaultdict(set)
```

Comment: What about making a `User` and `Book` class and pass around these instances? Using strings like this will not make you you able to follow the relationships. You can store recommendations in the `User` class as just a list of books.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick 5 min mockup to show an alternative:

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, name, books=[], friends=[]):
        self.name = name
        self.books = books
        self.friends = friends

    def friendsbooks(self):
        books = set()
        for friend in self.friends:
            books.update(friend.books)
        return books

class Book:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        # Possibility of extending ..

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

books = [Book('Harry Potter'), Book('Master Algo')]
users = [
    User('A', books=[books[1]]),
    User('B', books=[books[0], books[1]]),
    User('C', books=[books[0]]),
]
users[0].friends = [users[1]]
users[1].friends = [users[0], users[2]]
users[2].friends = [users[0]]

print(users[2].friendsbooks())
```

Outputs:

```
{Master Algo, Harry Potter}
{Master Algo, Harry Potter}
{Master Algo}
```

It does get a bit more complicated to add the initial data, but you'll figure it out. There are definitely improvements that can be made.

Answer (score 0):

The following modifications fixed the issue:

```
from collections import defaultdict

class recommendation:            
    friendsgraph =  defaultdict(set)
    booksgraph =  defaultdict(set)

    def __init__(self, user, books, friends):
        self.name = user
        self.books  = books
        self.friends = friends

        recommendation.friendsgraph[user] =  friends
        recommendation.booksgraph[user] = books


    def friendsbooks(self):
        recommendation_list = set()
        for friend in self.friends:
           rec_books = recommendation.booksgraph[friend]
           if rec_books:
              recommendation_list.add(rec_books)
        return recommendation_list

A = recommendation('A',('Neverland Land'),('B'))
B = recommendation('B',('Harry Potter', 'Master Algo'),('A'))

print A.friendsbooks()
print B.friendsbooks()
```

Output:

```
{('Harry Potter', 'Master Algo')}
{'Neverland Land'}
```